# How to create a directory structure with Rake for a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rake-task

I have a Rails 3 app which needs to have some directories created. I'd like to have a rake task which I can run to do this as a sort of initialization procedure. Basically I'd like to do:  `rake app:create_dirs` or something similar. I tried using the "directory" commands but they seem to be only for dependencies in rake. Any ideas how to do this nicely? My dir structure needs to look like this:

```
public/content/0/0

public/content/0/1

public/content/0/2

...

public/content/1/0

public/content/1/1

...

public/content/n/m
```

where `n` is `0..9` and `m` is `0..9`

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, I don't know your exact application but the main point is to look into [FileUtils#mkdir_p](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/FileUtils.html#M001763)

```
require 'fileutils'

(0..9).each do |n|
  (0..9).each do |m|
    FileUtils.mkdir_p("#{Rails.public_path}/content/#{n}/#{m}")
  end
end
```